# To transform arrays in JS

Tags: javascript, php

Help, please.

How is it possible in JS to transform these arrays:

```
$ar1 = array('Shop 1', 15, 25, 30);
$ar2 = array('Shop 2', 25, 45, 50);
$ar3 = array('Month', 1, 2, 3);
```

to this:

```
$values = array(
   array('Month', 'Shop 1', 'Shop 2'),
   array('1', 15, 25),
   array('2', 25, 45),
   array('3', 30, 50),
);
```

in PHP I can do it as follow:

```
$result = array_map(function($a,$b,$c){ return [$a,$b,$c]; }, $ar3,$ar1,$ar2);
```

or like that:

```
function flip($arr) {
$result = array();
foreach ($arr as $index => $list) {
    foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
        $result[$key][$index] = $value;
    }
}
return $result;
}

$values = flip([$ar3, $ar1, $ar2]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert array of rows to array of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971389/convert-array-of-rows-to-array-of-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` in Javascript. It passes the array index as an argument to the callback, which you can then use to access the other two arrays.

```js
var arr1 = ['Shop 1', 15, 25, 30];
var arr2 = ['Shop 2', 25, 45, 50];
var arr3 = ['Month', 1, 2, 3];

var result = arr3.map(function(element, index) {
  return [element, arr1[index], arr2[index]];
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```js
var arr1 = ['Shop 1', 15, 25, 30];
var arr2 = ['Shop 2', 25, 45, 50];
var arr3 = ['Month', 1, 2, 3];

var res = [];
Object.keys(arr3)
      .forEach(function(key){
          res.push([arr3[key].toString(), arr1[key], arr2[key]]); 
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

With proper arrays, you could transform the single arrays with a nested loop for the result.

```js
var array1 = ['Shop 1', 15, 25, 30],
    array2 = ['Shop 2', 25, 45, 50],
    array3 = ['Month', 1, 2, 3],
    result = [array3, array1, array2].reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        a.forEach(function (b, j) {
            r[j] = r[j] || [];
            r[j][i] = b;
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```